# Can we book Uber cabs using iOS Uber Kit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uber-api

I have downloaded Uberkit from the below github link.

https://github.com/sachinkesiraju/UberKit

With this kit I am getting Uber type, price, capacity etc. However I have a doubt like Can we book Uber cabs from my iOS app by using above Uberkit?

Comment: if you integreated in your app, then you can book,it is possible

Comment: I have integrated Uberkit into my app with the help of Cocoapods, but I have no idea which class I have to use? Can I book a uber cab without deep linking to Uber app? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if Uber app is installed in your device it redirect to your app else it redirect to safari for book the cab.

Comment: So there is no direct method in the Uberkit to book a cab right? We have to redirect to the Uber app? After we book a cab using Uber app will it redirect back to my app?

Answer (score 2):

**Parameter Types**

[latitude floatValue] --> your current Latitude

[longitude floatValue] --> your current Longitude

latitud  --> your DropPlace latitude

longitud  --> your DropPlace longitude

```
[self.lblSubTitle.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] --> drop address 

//manodary

[[getHuberDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"productID"]] --> Uber Type Booking ID


NSString *getUberDetails=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"client_id=PassyourUberID&action=setPickup&pickup[latitude]=%f&pickup[longitude]=%f&pickup[nickname]=OuttAPP&dropoff[latitude]=%f&dropoff[longitude]=%f&dropoff[nickname]=%@&product_id=%@",[latitude floatValue],[longitude floatValue],latitud,longitud,[self.lblSubTitle.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],[[getHuberDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"productID"]];


if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"uber://"]])
{


    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"uber://?%@",getUberDetails]]];

}
else
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://m.uber.com/?%@",getUberDetails]]];
}
```

Comment: there is no call back for deep link in ios , we need to come on maually to our app

Comment: would you need any assistance related to this

Comment: Thanks for your comments Karthik. I have no doubts reg this.